# Build/Deploy SSRS with TFS 2010

Tags: msbuild, reporting-services, tfsbuild, rs.exe

I am trying to build and deploy an SSRS project (rptproj) but MSBuild does not support this project type.  What can I use to build and deploy this project?

I looks like I can use RS.EXE and Dev Env.  What are the benefits of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is recommended to install Visual Studio on the TFS Build machine to support building various types of projects that MSBuild alone does not support. You don't have to worry about licensing because as long as you have a Visual Studio license then you can put it on all of your machines.

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049969/tfs-build-is-failing-because-of-missing-programs).

Comment: I ended up installing Visual Studio.  Seems to work fine.  Thanks.